# What is the difference between a ".com" file and a ".bin" file?

Tags: x86, operating-system, dos, bootloader, file-format

I'm working on a kernel based on Assembly x86 programming language. I just wondered what is the difference between .bin files and .com files. Can I boot from a .com file? Where and how to use .com files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking about DOS executables, then a [.COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file) file has very little structure. It's first byte corresponds to IP=0x100. When DOS starts it, it sets CS=DS=ES=SS=segment into which the file is loaded. IP is 0x100, SP is typically close to 0xFFFE (unless DOS is short of memory). The space between offset 0 and 0x100 has some control information, the [Program Segment Prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix), which includes the command line with arguments.

There's no generally agreed-on structure of a .BIN file. It can be anything. DOS doesn't recognize it.

The BIOS (unless we're talking about UEFI) doesn't support any executable format. It just loads the very first sector from the disk (to physical address 0x7C00) and passes control to it (setting CS:IP to either 0:0x7C00 or 0x7C0:0). The sector must be able to load (using BIOS int 0x13) more sectors from the disk somehow.

IOW, the BIOS generally can't load a whole .COM program and successfully start it. Even for such a simple task one would need a first stage boot loader. But it can be done. See e.g. my [BootProg](https://github.com/alexfru/BootProg). It can load DOS .COMs and .EXEs.

Comment: Most BIOSes do check for a valid boot signature at the end of the 512-byte MBR sector (`dw 0xAA55`).  Also, some BIOSes will overwrite part of the 512 bytes with disk partition info (BPB), so there is some structure.  [How to stop the BIOS (BPB) from overwriting parts of the bootloader?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45738303) and MichaelPetch's answer shows the structure that the BIOS fills in: 
 [Custom bootloader booted via USB drive produces incorrect output on some computers](//stackoverflow.com/q/47277702).

Comment: The boot sector itself can be a self-contained program, it doesn't *have* to load more code from disk if your code fits in 510 bytes (or 510-50).

Comment: @PeterCordes Right. I wasn't answering what the BIOS expects, I was more answering the direct question about .COM files.

Comment: Right, sure.  I guess my point is that a legacy BIOS MBR is pretty darn close to what you could call an executable file format, with a magic number and everything.  And yes, `.com` is just based on the filename, not a file "format", and it tells DOS to just load the whole file into RAM a certain way.

Comment: So, we specify the 0x7c00 address at the top of our code as `org 0x7c00`. Even the program start executing by the top.

Comment: @BurakYeniçeri It's a common option. And then you want to make sure that CS is 0. For that you can use a far jump to 0:some_label.

Comment: @PeterCordes For standard floppy drives most BIOSes don't check for a valid boot signature.  It's also not accurate to say that MBRs have "a magic number and everything", as they have a magic number and nothing else.

Comment: @RossRidge: I meant that the BPB which gets filled in by the loader is further structure.  But yeah, there's no other metadata like segments for a program-loader.